# Location services on smartphones - which physical network does it use?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, smartphone, cellular

I was pleasantly surprised to find that my iPhone was able to detect my location in India despite disabling my expensive data roaming (I live in the USA and use AT & T). I did have my cellular roaming turned on (local provider being Airtel).

I had always assumed that without data networking enabled, my apps would not be able to find out my location (e.g. photo EXIF geotagging, Google Maps current location dot). Now that I know this is untrue, I am curious which network location services utilizes. I'm assuming it's not a separate physical network but is carried via one of data services network or cellular network. Which one is it? And if it's the data network, how does it work without data services enabled?

Comment: Probably GPS...

Comment: So is my USA carrier able to provide that to me with no deal with a foreign carrier? I'm wondering whether I get charged extra

Comment: It has nothing to do with carrier, IIRC you could throw your SIM out your car window and GPS would still work. (heck, the phone never tells the carrier it's even using GPS usually as GPS is just signals being transmitted from satellites, there's not response from your phone)

Comment: Does the phone communicate directly with a GPS satellite? Or is there some intermediate antenna?

Comment: It communicates directly.

Comment: I'll mark your response correct if you post it as an answer

Comment: It can also use wifi & phone mast triangulation, even with data roaming off. I have roaming permanently off, but it doesn't prevent me using mapping & geolocation-reliant apps abroad [so long as I have my maps pre-loaded to the phone]

Comment: Y'know why most people call location services on a phone "GPS"? Because *it uses GPS*.

Comment: Phones are typically off topic for SU anyhow....

Comment: Instead of telling me where I shouldn't post it, how about telling me where I SHOULD post it? I was told to post it here when I had posted it in another site: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24996/location-services-on-smartphones-which-physical-network-does-it-use?noredirect=1#comment39064_24996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location services on most smartphones made in the last 7-8 years directly communicates with GPS satellites to get location.

From my comment:

> It has nothing to do with carrier, IIRC you could throw your SIM out your car window and GPS would still work. (heck, the phone never tells the carrier it's even using GPS usually as GPS is just signals being transmitted from satellites, there's not response from your phone)